# Unexpected behavior for % 5 with a dividend of zero

Tags: c++, operators, modulo

I have following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<exception>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        abort();
      }
   }
}
```

but it  only writes 0 and says that abort was called why? i think it  should ouput
0 1 2 3 4  and than exit program yes?

Comment: I can't believe you think this question is about the `abort()` function. I have corrected your question title.

Comment: davit - you should accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of `%` as "remainder after division."  `0 / 5` equals 0 with a remainder of 0.

Answer (score 1):

when `i` is 0, `0 % 5` equals 0